# Render a page using expressJS-swaggerui

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui

I am getting a blank page when I tried call a route that renders a swaggerUI from expressJS using the swagger-ui-express plugin.

Basically , I have a route '/api-docs/prd'. When the route is called , I would like to download the file, parse  and sent the json to swagger UI.

So far, I have a function to download the file and render the data in SwaggerUI **(this works)** .

```
const downloadAsYAML = async () => {
  const bucket ='buc';
  const path = 'openapi_prd.yaml';
 const file = await new Storage()
   .bucket(bucket)
   .file(path)
   .download();
  var x = yaml.parse(file[0].toString('utf8'))
  return x;
}

downloadAsYAML().then((res)=>{
app.use('/api-docs/prd', swaggerUi.serveFiles(res, options), swaggerUi.setup(null,options));
});
```

However, I want a route that download the file first and then call the swaggerUI . Example: when the route is called , download file and then pass the value to swaggerUI

```
 app.get('/api-docs/prd', function(req, res, next){
  downloadAsYAML('openapi_prd.yaml').then((result)=>{
    swaggerDocument=result;  //swaggerDocument is define with null
  });
  next();
}, swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocument, options), swaggerUi.setup());
```

The above code just display a blank screen and I see the error below in the console.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3001/api-docs/prd/swagger-ui.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

swagger-ui-bundle.js:1   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the `next()` function is called before the Promise generated from `downloadAsYAML` can resolve.

Try something like this:

```js
app.get('/api-docs/prd', function(req, res, next){
  downloadAsYAML('openapi_prd.yaml').then((result)=>{
    swaggerDocument=result;
    next(); // -> ensure next() is only called after setting `swaggerDocument`
  });
}, swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocument, options), swaggerUi.setup());
```

or with `async/await`

```js
app.get('/api-docs/prd', async function(req, res, next){
  swaggerDocument = await downloadAsYAML('openapi_prd.yaml')
  next()
}, swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocument, options), swaggerUi.setup());
```

Comment: Thanks .. same issue.
I see errors in the console which I did not get with the first option. Will paste in the question